# Linked list head element

Tags: java, linked-list

In data structure, when assigning the following **head = head.next**, I believe that the head then points to the next element. 
But what if I wrote: **head.next = head** , will the operation still be the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

`head.next = head` would create a cyclic list with a single element, since the `head` of the list would point to itself.

Comment: Only if `head != null` otherwise it's NPE

Comment: @cricket_007 that's true

Comment: Thanks for your help!